# How To Setup Up Email Sending Authentication with my server?

Tags: email, debian, phpmailer

I want my server to authenticate all outgoing emails from my server. At the domain provider, I record the SPF record and the authentication works perfectly. However, I also want my server to authenticate outbound mail from even a gmail email address. I sent the mail with PHPMailer and gave it a try, but when I read the mail, gmail prompts me that the email may not have been sent by the sender. The email header is not encrypted. For other email providers, I see that their own server authenticates even if they use gmail email addresses. What do I need to do to have my server authenticate outgoing mail from my server (including using a gmail email address). I want to build a newsletter sending service. Of course, I do not want to commit fraud and unethical activities. Customers can only use specific email addresses after they have previously activated it. So the email will only be used by the rightful owner of the email address. I just don’t know how to get my server to authenticate when sending these emails

Picture 1 shows that using the gmail address (not authenticated by the server, google will issue a warning in the mail) Picture 2 shows that a gmail address was also used and authenticated by a service provider's server (not gmail), so gmail accepted it and of course the header indicates which server was the authenticator. I also want mail sent from my own server to be authenticated by my own server.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w45lK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you want to send from a gmail address, you *must* send through gmail servers. Gmail's SPF settings do not allow other email sources. I would expect that the one that looks like it was sending from somewhere else actually sent through gmail, but it can still set an SMTP envelope sender that points to itself, and can also do DKIM signing from that address.

Comment: I have tried several newsletter sending services, including mailchimp. By signing up for mailchimp and activating my account, I can now send mail from my gmail address without entering my email account password, so this is not an smtp connection. The e-mail is not sent by gmail, but by the server of the newsletter and its own server.